# How to Convert Image to Base64Encode String

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, base64, encode

How to convert Image to base64String.

```
  UIImage * someImage = [UIImage imageNamed: @"page4.png"];
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(someImage, 1.0);
//    NSString *encodedString = [imageData base64EncodedDataWithOptions:NSDataBase64EncodingEndLineWithLineFeed];
      NSString *base64 = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:imageData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] ;
    if (base64){
       NSLog(@"Base 64 %@",base64);
      }
```

I the above code gives me empty  value for base64 string.

@All 
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The encoding is not correct..

Try this:

```
NSString *base64 = [imageData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];
```

Answer (score 1):

### Issue

You are getting empty data because you have a `.png` format of image trying to get data with `UIImageJPEGRepresentation`

### Solution

You need to use `UIImagePNGRepresentation`

From [Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uikitfunctionreference/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIImagePNGRepresentation):

```
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation (someImage);
```

---

*P.S `UIImagePNGRepresentation` has no compression factor, it has just the image parameter*

Answer (score 1):

```
//For Encoding
UIImage * someImage = [UIImage imageNamed: @"page4.png"];
NSData *imageData=UIImagePNGRepresentation(someImage);
NSString *base64 = [imageData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];

// For Decoding
NSData *data=[[NSData alloc]initWithBase64EncodedString:base64 options:NSDataBase64DecodingIgnoreUnknownCharacters];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```